# Циклические сбои в работе nrf24l01+

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

Столкнулся с не совсем корректной работой с модулями nrf24l01+. У меня проект умного дома. Строю свой протокол дабы обойти ограничение в 6 устройств. Проблема в том что модули циклически именно с какой-то системой (как по мне) перестают отвечать на запросы. Если модуль будет один то все будет ОК!(за исключением редких ошибок).
База NodeMCU 1.0 (esp8266 12-e).
Сенсоры Arduino Nano
(Код для разных сенсоров был изменен, тобиж были измены труби прослушивания и переменная id_sensor)
Прикол в том, что при одном сенсоре все работает правильно и стабильно, но при подключении второго, идут циклические ошибки, тоесть один из сенсоров попросту не отвечает на запрос!
**Код базы**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(D4, D8);
struct message {
  uint8_t id;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t data;
};
struct info_ {
  uint8_t id_sensor;
  uint8_t type_sensor;
  int16_t v_bat;
  uint8_t status_sensor;
  uint8_t signal_lvl;
  uint8_t person_pipe[1][6];
};
message rx_data;
info_ reg_pack;
uint8_t address[20][6] = {"0Node", "1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "5Node", "9Node"}; //0-Заглушка;1-Alarms;2-Reg; 3-Get_data; Another sesors!
boolean get_data_all() {
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.powerUp();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[4]);
  uint8_t data = 101;
  boolean tx = radio.write(&data, sizeof(data));
  Serial.print("TX status:");
  Serial.println(tx);
  radio.startListening();
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (i < 15) {
    if (radio.available()) {
      break;
    }
    i++;
    delay(150);
  }
  if (i == 15) {
    Serial.println("1 sensor ban =(");
  }
  else {
    message rx_firsth;
    Serial.print("Data recived! ");
    radio.read(&rx_firsth, sizeof(rx_firsth));
    Serial.print("Id:");
    Serial.print(rx_firsth.id);
    Serial.print(" Data:");
    Serial.print(rx_firsth.data);
  }
  delay(150);
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.powerUp();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[5]);
  uint8_t data2 = 101;
  boolean tx2 = radio.write(&data2, sizeof(data2));
  Serial.print("TX2 status:");
  Serial.println(tx2);
  radio.startListening();
  uint8_t i2 = 0;
  while (i2 < 15) {
    if (radio.available()) {
      break;
    }
    i2++;
    delay(150);
  }
  if (i2 == 15) {
    Serial.println("2 sensor ban =(");
  }
  else {
    message rx_two;
    Serial.print("Data recived! ");
    radio.read(&rx_two, sizeof(rx_two));
    Serial.print("Id:");
    Serial.print(rx_two.id);
    Serial.print(" Data:");
    Serial.print(rx_two.data);
  }
  return true;
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.setChannel(120);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[1]);
  radio.setAutoAck(1, true);
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, address[2]);//Reg pipe
  radio.setAutoAck(2, true);
  radio.openReadingPipe(3, address[3]);//Data-info pipe
  radio.setAutoAck(3, true);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[0]);//Trash pipe
  radio.setRetries(3, 15);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.powerUp();

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String buffer_ = Serial.readString();
    if (buffer_ == "tx") {
      Serial.println("Start sending...");
      get_data_all();
    }
  }
}
```

**Код сенсора**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10);
uint8_t id_sensor = 19;
uint8_t type_sensor = 1;
struct message {
  uint8_t id;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t data;
};
struct info_ {
  uint8_t id_sensor;
  uint8_t type_sensor;
  int16_t v_bat;
  uint8_t status_sensor;
  uint8_t signal_lvl;
  uint8_t person_pipe[1][6];
};
message rx_data;
info_ reg_pack;
uint8_t address[20][6] = {"0Node", "1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "5Node", "9Node"}; //0-Заглушка;1-Alarms;2-Reg; 3-Get_data; Another sesors!
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.setChannel(120);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[5]);
  radio.setAutoAck(1, true);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[3]);
  radio.setRetries(3, 15);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_1MBPS);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.powerUp();

}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    uint8_t lol = 0;
    radio.read(&lol, sizeof(lol));
    Serial.println("Radio available!");
    radio.stopListening();
    radio.powerUp();
    radio.openWritingPipe(address[3]);
    message mess;
    mess.id = id_sensor;
    mess.type = type_sensor;
    mess.data = (uint8_t)random(1,20);
    boolean tx = radio.write(&mess, sizeof(mess));
    Serial.print("Send status:");
    Serial.println(tx);
    radio.startListening();
  }
}
```

**Лог(базы)**
[image: Лог работы базы]

Comment: Прикол в том, что при одном сенсоре все работает правильно и стабильно, но при подключении второго, идут циклические ошибки, тоесть один из сенсоров попросту не отвечает на запрос!

Comment: Надеюсь, питание на nrf24l01 подаете через отдельный стабилизатор?

Comment: Т.к. китайцы не припаивают к антенне конденсатор пассивной нагрузки, то в пределах квартиры можете уменьшить мощность до минимальной `RF24_PA_MIN`, этого более чем хватает. Либо сделать вокруг антенны пару витков провода с толстой изоляцией. Либо сделать правильно и припаять на место конденсатор 1-2 пикафарад.

Comment: @ГеннадийП
 Питание конечно через стаб(амс1117) по питанию кондеры, и мощность я ставил только на low, так было написано на форуме =)
Ну пока проблема решена простым отключением autoAck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем проблема решена! Надо было отключить autoAck!
Проблема скорее всего была из-за того что я постоянно менял трубы и nrf не мог ловить пакет об успешной передачи, и собственно датчик также не всегда отправлял данные
**База**

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(D4, D8);
struct message {
  uint8_t id;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t data;
};
struct info_ {
  uint8_t id_sensor;
  uint8_t type_sensor;
  int16_t v_bat;
  uint8_t status_sensor;
  uint8_t signal_lvl;
  uint8_t person_pipe[1][6];
};
message rx_data;
info_ reg_pack;
uint8_t address[20][6] = {"0Node", "1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "5Node", "9Node"}; //0-Заглушка;1-Alarms;2-Reg; 3-Get_data; Another sesors!
void radio_init() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setChannel(120);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[1]);
  radio.setAutoAck(1, false);
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, address[2]);//Reg pipe
  radio.setAutoAck(2, false);
  radio.openReadingPipe(3, address[3]);//Data-info pipe
  radio.setAutoAck(3, false);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[0]);//Trash pipe
  radio.setRetries(3, 15);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.powerUp();
}
boolean get_data_all() {
  radio_init();
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.powerUp();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[4]);
  uint8_t data = 101;
  boolean tx = radio.write(&data, sizeof(data));
  Serial.print("TX status:");
  Serial.println(tx);
  radio.startListening();
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (i < 15) {
    if (radio.available()) {
      break;
    }
    i++;
    delay(150);
  }
  if (i == 15) {
    Serial.println("1 sensor ban =(");
  }
  else {
    message rx_firsth;
    Serial.print("Data recived! ");
    radio.read(&rx_firsth, sizeof(rx_firsth));
    Serial.print("Id:");
    Serial.print(rx_firsth.id);
    Serial.print(" Data:");
    Serial.print(rx_firsth.data);
  }
  delay(150);
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.powerUp();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[5]);
  uint8_t data2 = 101;
  boolean tx2 = radio.write(&data2, sizeof(data2));
  Serial.print("TX2 status:");
  Serial.println(tx2);
  radio.startListening();
  uint8_t i2 = 0;
  while (i2 < 15) {
    if (radio.available()) {
      break;
    }
    i2++;
    delay(150);
  }
  if (i2 == 15) {
    Serial.println("2 sensor ban =(");
  }
  else {
    message rx_two;
    Serial.print("Data recived! ");
    radio.read(&rx_two, sizeof(rx_two));
    Serial.print("Id:");
    Serial.print(rx_two.id);
    Serial.print(" Data:");
    Serial.print(rx_two.data);
  }
  return true;
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio_init();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String buffer_ = Serial.readString();
    if (buffer_ == "tx") {
      Serial.println("Start sending...");
      get_data_all();
    }
  }
}
```

**Сенсор**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10);
uint8_t id_sensor = 19;
uint8_t type_sensor = 1;
struct message {
  uint8_t id;
  uint8_t type;
  uint8_t data;
};
struct info_ {
  uint8_t id_sensor;
  uint8_t type_sensor;
  int16_t v_bat;
  uint8_t status_sensor;
  uint8_t signal_lvl;
  uint8_t person_pipe[1][6];
};
message rx_data;
info_ reg_pack;
uint8_t address[20][6] = {"0Node", "1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "5Node", "9Node"}; //0-Заглушка;1-Alarms;2-Reg; 3-Get_data; Another sesors!
void radio_init() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setChannel(120);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[5]);
  radio.setAutoAck(1, false);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[3]);
  radio.setRetries(3, 15);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.powerUp();
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //radio_init();
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setChannel(120);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[5]);
  radio.setAutoAck(1, false);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[3]);
  radio.setRetries(3, 15);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.powerUp();
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    uint8_t lol = 0;
    //radio_init();
    delay(10);
    radio.read(&lol, sizeof(lol));
    Serial.println("Radio available!");
    radio.stopListening();
    radio.powerUp();
    radio.openWritingPipe(address[3]);
    message mess;
    mess.id = id_sensor;
    mess.type = type_sensor;
    mess.data = (uint8_t)random(1, 20);
    boolean tx = radio.write(&mess, sizeof(mess));
    Serial.print("Send status:");
    Serial.println(tx);
    radio.startListening();
  }
}
```

Comment: @magrif
Понял, ответ дополнил